# Error parsing data from JSON response "no such file or directory" responded

Tags: php, android, json

I am developing a login system in my android application.
While I try to login my application is crashed and I get the following error:

```
05-11 08:50:57.954: E/JSON Parser(2817): Error parsing data [Value No of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject] No such file or directory
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817): Process: com.example.matant.mlnxstore, PID: 2817
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:102)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-11 08:50:57.955: E/AndroidRuntime(2817):     ... 4 more
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a824b2 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:68)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-11 08:50:59.214: E/WindowManager(2817):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Maybe the PHP code is wrong?

this is my JSONparser:

```
package com.example.matant.mlnxstore.library;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

/**
 * Created by matant on 4/30/2015.
 */
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jsonObj;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser(){

    }

    public  JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) throws IOException {
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();



        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            { e.printStackTrace(); }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            { e.printStackTrace(); }

        catch (IOException e)
        { e.printStackTrace(); }

        try{
            // Create a BufferedReader
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            //declaring string builder

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            //string to store JSON Object
            String strline = null;

            //Building while we have string !equal null.
            while ((strline = reader.readLine())!=null){
                str.append(strline+"\n");
            }

            //close input stream
            is.close();
            //string builder data conversion to string
            json = str.toString();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("error", "Error occured while converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        //try block used for parsing a string to a json object
        try{
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("json Parsering","" + e.toString());
        }

        return jsonObj;

    }

    public  JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,String params,JSONArray js){
        //make http req

       try {
           //checking req method
           if(method == "POST"){
               HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setHeader("json",params);
               httpPost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",js);

               //httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params));
              // Log.d("HttPost",params);
               HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
               is = httpEntity.getContent();


           }
       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           Log.d("UnsupportedEncodingException",e.toString());
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch (Exception e){
           Log.e("HTTP","Error in http connection"+e.toString());
       }
        try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String strline = null;
            while((strline = reader.readLine())!= null){

                str.append(strline + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = str.toString();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //now will try to parse string into JSON
        try{
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage() + "] " + json);

        }

        return jsonObj;
    }
}
```

this is the LogCat Debug:

```
  05-11 07:52:58.352: D/request(2595): {"tag":"login","email":"t@m.com","password":"1234"}
05-11 07:52:58.404: W/EGL_emulation(2595): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-11 07:52:58.404: W/OpenGLRenderer(2595): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb0a133a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-11 07:52:58.612: E/JSON Parser(2595): Error parsing data [Value No of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject] No such file or directory
05-11 07:52:58.612: D/Login attempt result(2595): {"tag":"login","error":true,"errror_msg":"tag parameter is missing"}
05-11 07:52:58.612: W/System.err(2595): org.json.JSONException: No value for error_msg
05-11 07:52:58.612: W/System.err(2595):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
05-11 07:52:58.612: W/System.err(2595):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
05-11 07:52:58.612: W/System.err(2595):     at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:125)
05-11 07:52:58.612: W/System.err(2595):     at com.example.matant.mlnxstore.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
05-11 07:52:58.632: W/System.err(2595):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-11 07:52:58.632: W/System.err(2595):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-11 07:52:58.632: W/System.err(2595):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-11 07:52:58.632: W/System.err(2595):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-11 07:52:58.632: W/System.err(2595):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-11 07:52:58.632: W/System.err(2595):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

this is my index.php:

```
  <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matant
 * Date: 4/29/2015
 * Time: 4:57 PM
 */
$data = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
$data = json_decode($data);
$temp = $data->tag;

if($temp == 'login')
{
    $tag = $data->tag;;
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error"=>FALSE);
    //login
    if($tag == 'login')
    {
        $email = $data->email;
        $password = $data->password;

        $user = $db->getUserDet($email,$password);

        if($user != false){
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["user"]["username"] = $user["usern"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            echo json_encode($response);

        }else
        {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["errror_msg"] = "Incorrect Email or Password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

    }else
    {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["errror_msg"] = "This is not Login request!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}

else {

    $response["tag"] = $temp;
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["errror_msg"] = "tag parameter is missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

this is my main activity:

```
   package com.example.matant.mlnxstore;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.matant.mlnxstore.library.JSONParser;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
   private EditText user,pass;
    private Button login;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //JSON Parser Class

    JSONParser jsonp = new JSONParser();
    private static final String URL = "http://gpsport.byethost12.com/mlnxstore/index.php";
    private static final  String TAG_Success = "error";
    private static final  String TAG_Message = "error_msg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPass);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLgn);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);

    }





    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonLgn:
                            new AttemptLogin().execute();
             default:
                 break;
        }

    }
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog((MainActivity.this));
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for Login..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            boolean success = false;
            String email = user.getText().toString();
            String password  = pass.getText().toString();



            /*Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("tag","login");
            params.put("email",email);
            params.put("password",password);*/

            JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
            try {
                js.put("tag","login");
                js.put("email",email);
                js.put("password",password);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("request", js.toString());

            JSONArray postjs = new JSONArray();
            postjs.put(js);

            //JSONObject jsh = new JSONObject();


            JSONObject json = jsonp.makeHttpRequest(URL,"POST",js.toString(),postjs);

            Log.d("Login attempt result",json.toString());

            try {
                success = json.getBoolean(TAG_Success);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(success == false)
            {
                Log.d("Successfuly Loged in!",json.toString());
                Intent ii = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HelloWorld.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(ii);
                try {

                    return  json.getString(TAG_Message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                try {
                    return json.getString(TAG_Message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected  void onPostExecute(String message){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(message != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `error_msg` does not exists in your response JSON. I suspect an error parsing issue...

Comment: Do you have a special kind of server setup and / or php version that provides `$_SERVER['HTTP_JSON']`? Note that there is no such value available normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

05-11 07:52:58.612: D/Login attempt result(2595): {"tag":"login","error":true,"errror_msg":"tag parameter is missing"}

The backend expects something more/else from your request. Check the documentation.

Comment: i dont know why because you can see that the tag = "login" and for some reason he does not get inside the if statment

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$response["error_msg"] = "tag parameter is missing";
```

Insead of

```
$response["errror_msg"] = "tag parameter is missing";
```

in your index.php

Answer (score 0):

Be more attentive,
Json object has key "errror_msg" with  3 "r" in key word (php code generates such key)

but in Android app you trying to get value for "error_msg" key only with 2 "r" so fix name of key, use everywhere "error_msg" or "errror_msg"

result(2595): {"tag":"login","error":true,"errror_msg":"tag parameter is missing"}
05-11 07:52:58.612: W/System.err(2595): org.json.JSONException: No value for error_msg